# Reference issue with Spring 3.0/Hibernate config files

Tags: security, hibernate, spring

All,

I originally had my setup like this and everything worked as expected.

```
WEB-INF
|--spring-servlet.xml
|--classes
   |--hibernate-cfg.xml
```

spring-servlet.xml had

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo" />
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="dataSource" ...
<bean id="sessionFactory" ...
<bean id="transactionManager" ...
<bean ...
```

hibernate-cfg.xml had

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping ...
```

I wanted to add Spring Security to the mix to handle user authentication.  To get this to work, I had to refactor some stuff.  My new setup looks like this:

```
WEB-INF
|--spring-servlet.xml
|--classes
   |--datasource-cfg.xml
   |--hibernate-cfg.xml
```

spring-servlet.xml has

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo" />
<bean ...
```

datasource-cfg.xml has

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="dataSource" ...
<bean id="sessionFactory" ...
<bean id="transactionManager" ...
```

hibernate-cfg.xml has

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping ...
```

The authentication piece now works, but the previously working pieces no longer work.

I now get the following message:

```
No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
```

How can I get my app to work with Spring Security and have all the datasource/hibernate stuff in one place?

Comment: How are you configuring spring to use the additional config file?

Comment: Ahh, you might be onto something.  Spring Security makes you add it to the classpath in web.xml.      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            classpath:datasource-cfg.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the classpath so that the rest of the app can see datasource-cfg.xml  Would that be added to spring-servlet.xml, web.xml, etc?

Comment: @user973479: Which classes are using `@Transactional`? Which file are they declared in?

Comment: There's tons of Transactional Annotations throughout the app for handling CRUD stuff, which used to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in the web.xml should be enough.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    classpath:datasource-cfg.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

I wouldn't mix-and-match where the config files go, however; IMO it's best to keep them all in one place, probably on the classpath.

Comment: I already have those in my web.xml, so there must be something else going on I'm not seeing

Comment: @user973479 Are you sure the datasource config file is being deployed?

Comment: Yes, because the authentication piece works, which relies on it

Comment: I got it.  I had to manually overwrite the default for the applicationContext and add the new file to the classpath for the DispatchServlet.  This is similar to what's shown above, except this references a different xml file. (So, this needs to be done as well as the one shown above)

          <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
                classpath:datasource.xml
            </param-value>

Comment: @user973479 Ah, yeah, sorry; I wasn't copying from an existing project. I'll update the answer with your additional information. Glad you worked it out--I spaced on that :/ Wouldn't putting the applicationContext in the context-param work, though?